# plugin not working with ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a jquery [rating plugin](http://rateit.codeplex.com/) and I am using this on a div like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="highlighted" class="span6">
<div class="row">
    <div id="high-desc" class="span4">
        <span class="movie-title fat"><a class="strong" href="movies.jsp?id=5">Watchmen</a> (2009)</span><br />
        <div id="rating"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#rating").rateit({
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    step: 1
});
```

It works great. However, when I replace the content of `div#highlighted` by some other content (like below), then the plugin doesn't work.

```
$('// some link').on("click", function(){ 
    var Id = // some id
    title="reco_product_stream.jsp?type=high&id="+Id;
    ('#highlighted').load(title);
});
```

I even tried reloading the plugin on every ajax call like this :

```
$('// some link').on("click", function(){ 
    var Id = // some id
    title="reco_product_stream.jsp?type=high&id="+Id;
    ('#highlighted').load(title);
    $("#rating").rateit({max: 10, min: 0, step:1});
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: It is just a suggestion, but the following official example might help you: http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm#ex_11
(example #11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('// some link').on("click", function(){ 
    var Id = // some id
    title="reco_product_stream.jsp?type=high&id="+Id;
    $('#highlighted').load(title);
    $("#rating").rateit({max: 10, min: 0, step:1});
});
```

In above your code `$("#rating").rateit({max: 10, min: 0, step:1});` executes before .load finishes loading.

Use it with .load callback.

```
$('#highlighted').load(title, function(){
 $("#rating").rateit({max: 10, min: 0, step:1});
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks! Is this the standard way to enable jquery on ajax-loaded content, i.e by running script as a callback, or just a work-around ?

Comment: By default, all requests are sent asynchronously that time you need a callback method.

Answer (score 3):

You do need to reinitialise the plugin on dynamically added content.

To do that, you have to wait for the request to complete by using a callback function.

jQuery's `load` method is asyncronous like most ajax methods.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('// some link').on("click", function(){ 
    var Id = // some id
    title="reco_product_stream.jsp?type=high&id="+Id;
    ('#highlighted').load(title,function(){ //callback executes after load
        $("#rating").rateit({max: 10, min: 0, step:1});
    });
});
```